# Ionic [Angular] - Reactive form: after using setValue() selectionStart/End doesn't move cursor

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework

I want to make a responsive form with input handler that puts "!" sign (via setValue()) at the end of the input field after keyboard input occurred. At the same time I want that after input occurred the cursor moves to the beginning of the input field and I use for that 'selectionStart/selectionEnd' properties of the input tag.

If I'm using plain html , everything works fine. But with ionic input it doesn't work and the cursor moves to the end after the keyboard input occurred. As  is a wrapper for another input, I tried both setting selectionStart/selectionEnd properties for initial ion-input and its child but without success.

How to cause the cursor to move to the beginning of the input field in Ionic input after changing form control value in ts file?

home.page.ts:

```js
export class HomePage {
  form = new FormGroup({
    amount: new FormControl(''),
  });
  constructor() {}

  amountHandler(event: any) {
    this.form.get('amount').setValue(event.target.value + '!');
    event.target.firstChild.selectionStart = 0;
    event.target.firstChild.selectionEnd = 0;
    //event.target.selectionStart = 0;
    //event.target.selectionEnd = 0;
  }
}
```

home.page.html:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Amount: </ion-label>
    <ion-input
      (ionInput)="amountHandler($event)"
      formControlName="amount"
    ></ion-input>    
  </ion-item>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`setValue()` is processed asynchronically, i.e. it happens after your `selectionStart`.
Try adding https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef#tick after the `setValue()`.

> tick() Invoke this method to explicitly process change detection and its side-effects.

Comment: Yes, I also found out that setValue() works asynchronically but for me it doesn't work with https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef#tick. I put in constructor's parameters "private appRef: ApplicationRef" and in ionInputHandler - `this.form.get('ionInput').setValue(event.target.value + '!'); ....this.appRef.tick();  input.selectionStart = 0;
input.selectionEnd = 0;`

Comment: I can confirm that it works perfectly in my case.